# python try the if statement on all objects of a class

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a for-loop which i am working on. It looks like this

```
for i, job  in enumerate(all_jobs_copy):
    machine = all_machines[0]
    if job.duration*machine.workspeed + machine.workload <= job.duedate:
        machine.add_job(job)
    else:
        duration, index = machine.get_longest_duration()
        if duration*machine.workspeed < job.duration*machine.workspeed:
            tardy_jobs.append(job)
        else:
            machine.erase_job(job, index)
    all_machines.sort(key = lambda x: x.workload*x.workspeed, reverse = False)
```

If the first if statement isn't true, it should try every other machine one by one. If the Jobs still don't fit on any of the machines it should go into the else statement.

At the moment it just tries the first machine and than goes into the else statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `for` and `break`...

```
for i, job  in enumerate(all_jobs_copy):
    for machine in all_machines:
        if job.duration*machine.workspeed + machine.workload <= job.duedate:
            machine.add_job(job)
            break
    else:
        duration, index = machine.get_longest_duration()
        if duration*machine.workspeed < job.duration*machine.workspeed:
            tardy_jobs.append(job)
        else:
            machine.erase_job(job, index)
    all_machines.sort(key = lambda x: x.workload*x.workspeed, reverse = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a second loop, and a `for/break/else` construction, it goes into `else` if no `break` has been used

```
for i, job in enumerate(all_jobs_copy):
    for machine in all_machines:
        if job.duration * machine.workspeed + machine.workload <= job.duedate:
            machine.add_job(job)
            break
    else:
        machine = all_machines[0]
        duration, index = machine.get_longest_duration()
        if duration * machine.workspeed < job.duration * machine.workspeed:
            tardy_jobs.append(job)
        else:
            machine.erase_job(job, index)
    all_machines.sort(key=lambda x: x.workload * x.workspeed, reverse=False)
```